# segfault after linking static library into both exe and shared lib

Tags: gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a program that statically links `glib` library and dynamically links a *shared library* that in turn also statically links the same `glib` library. When I run the program I get a segfault. After debugging in `gdb` I found that there is a `global static` variable defined in `glib` that's being set and it had different values in one call trace and than a later call trace. I then noticed that the variable addresses were different as well. So it seems like there are two copies of the `global static` variable? Shouldn't the executable override the symbol from shared library so there is only one global static variable in the executable during dynamic linking?

The other part of the story is that there is another executable that does the same as above, which seems to behave okay i.e., no segfault (haven't debugged to see if the different code paths load the same static variable). So perhaps this behavior is not deterministic.
*The following issue is happening with `gcc (8.3.1)` on Linux (`centos 7`).*

```
executableA (segfault)                          executableB (no segfault)
|            \                                     |        \
| (static)    \(shared)                            |(static) \(shared)
|              \                                   |          \
libglib-2.0.a   libA.so                        libglib-2.0.a   libA.so
                 |                                               |
                 | (static)                                      |(static)
                 |                                               |
              libglib-2.0.a                                  libglib-2.0.a
```

Comment: Note that the shared library is a third party library that I am building from source.

Comment: I have the same problem right now, could you give me some instructions, how you found the symbols that were a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it seems like there are two copies of the global static variable?

Yes, that is expected.

> Shouldn't the executable override the symbol from shared library so there is only one global static variable in the executable during dynamic linking?

A `static` variable *by definition* has local linkage -- it is not accessible from any other compilation unit, and is not exported from the shared library(ies).

You would have to make this variable (and any other similar variables) *non*-static and exported from both shared libraries. Only then will the dynamic loader bind all references to this variable to a single instance.

Note that linking separate copies of `libglib-2.0.a` into shared libraries *without* controlling symbol visibility is *asking* for trouble. Whatever you hoped to achieve by doing that, you are *not* achieving.

> there is another executable that does the same as above, which seems to behave okay

Ah, [programming by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpp20/the-pragmatic-programmer-20th-anniversary-edition/). The mine you stepped on didn't explode, so it should be ok to continue doing that.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "controlling symbol visibility"? glib library is statically linked into a third party library that I am building from source.

Comment: In any case since I know that glib is already statically linked into the third party shared library I don't need to link it again in my executable. But what if I hadn't known that or need to use glib before shared lib is loaded?